# How do you query a database in a AJAX call to a WebApi controller?

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a C# .NET application.

I have a webpage which features a search bar. When the User starts typing I use the Jquery `Keyup` function to automatically invoke a Webservice ( I am using a Controller call that extends ApiController).

The point of the Webservice is to return a list of data from the Database to the View, based on what the User has entered into the Search bar.

If the User types the Letter "A", then inside the Webservice function I will query the database for all the objects whose name begin with the Letter "A".

My question is how do I change my code into the correct JSON format so that it can be returned to the View. At the moment my query is returning IQueryable. The code below gets called fine by Ajax.

So, I believe that the problem in inside the Action method below. The parameter "term" is the letter that the User types into the search bar.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAllofTheProducts(string term)
{
   //var JsonArray = Json.stringify(products);

    List<string>vehicle;

      vehicle = db.Vechicle.Where(v => v.CarName.Equals(term) || v.CarName.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()) || v.CarName.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper()));

      //var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);    
     // return json;    
     return Json(vehicle);

}
```

**Update:** 
To expand on my question, I want to know how to change the result of my database query to a string so that I can pass it to a View. As this is an Ajax request and I can't directly pass the DB result.

Comment: What do want? you just have to convert your `vehicle` to json and return it.

Comment: Change `List<string>vehicle;` to `List<Vechicle>vehicle;`

Comment: Sure that worked I will test it now

Comment: You said that your code works fine, but how could it? `Vehicle != string`, so your code could never have compiled or ran at all.

Comment: You are right Ric I used var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vehicle);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're getting an error out of this code, or if you're receiving anything client-side.

Assuming you have no error, and you're receiving an empty JSON Array, I think you should explicitly cast your result as a list with .ToList() to make sure you get your data from the database. (As long as you don't ask to get an item from vehicle, it doesn't get loaded)

```
vehicle = db.Vechicle.Where(v => v.CarName.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())).ToList();
```

Also I removed some not needed part of your query

Searching for an exact match will return less results than a partial match.
Putting everything on the same case is a good idea, as it eliminates all differences between user input and the dataset, but then you have to choose either lowercasing or uppercasing (As they will give you the same result)

EDIT 2 :

I cannot comment as I have too few reputation so here is the answer :

Add the following

```
vehicle = db.Vechicle.Where(v => v.CarName.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())).Select(v => v.<NAME>).ToList();
```

As you're returning a list of vehicle, you only want to get Name of the brand, just replace  with the field name corresponding.

Comment: I am receiving the request server-side. I am just getting this error:

Comment: cannot implicitly convert type list<vechicle>  to string <string>

Comment: Actually I can comment on my own post, add the following before .ToList() : .Select(v => v.<NAME>), and replace <NAME> with the field you're looking for